# Regex for numeric string replacement

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regular expression for replacing several numbers (*20120906203631*) for a word in curly braces (*{{subst:REVISIONTIMESTAMP}}*) in a longer complicated string.

Example:

```
{{Zkontrolováno |20120906203631| [[Uživatel:Janak|MUDr. Jana Kovarova, PhD.]]|178116}}
```

to

```
{{Zkontrolováno |{{subst:REVISIONTIMESTAMP}}| [[Uživatel:Janak|MUDr. Jana Kovarova, PhD.]]|178116}}
```

Thank you for advicing me!

Comment: how about `178116` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use lookarounds like below.

**Regex:**

```
(?<=\|)\d+(?=\|)
```

The above regex matches one or more numbers which are present in-between `|` symbol.

- `(?<=\|)` Asserts that the match must be preceded by an `|` symbol.
- `\d+` matches one or more digits.
- `(?=\|)` Asserts that the match must be followed by `|` symbol.

**Replacement string:**

```
{{subst:REVISIONTIMESTAMP}}
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gO0cG7/3)